# Meta-analysis of standardized regression coefficient (beta coefficient)

Tags: meta-analysis

I am trying to do a meta analysis on the effect of smoking with hypertension. Some of the studies used 'beta coefficient' and its confidence interval as the effect of smoke exposure with increase in blood pressure. However, I did not know how to pool the beta coefficient from different studies. I am currently using Revman. Is it possible to pool 'beta coefficient' in Revman? If not, what program should I use (preferably with free version available).

I have read a similar meta analysis before: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31113399-effect-of-passive-exposure-to-cigarette-smoke-on-blood-pressure-in-children-and-adolescents-a-meta-analysis-of-epidemiologic-studies/ ; and they also pooled the beta coefficient of different studies.

Thank you.